# Grant read permission to multiple files without starting an intent

Tags: android-permissions, android-fileprovider

I'm coding an App which export all my MMS pics to multiple Download subfolders and I encounter some permission issues.
My code is extracting all my messages (text + images) and creating a html file with them following this tree :

```
My Download Folder/My App Name/Contact Name/
```

And in this folder, all the pics + my html file.

So, the paths to the pictures are dynamic and I can't define all of them in my provider_paths.xml.

What I've done :

Basically, at the end of my pic generating process, I need to grant my new generated image the read permission to further open it in a web page of myself.
The difficulty here is to keep the read permission even if the App is destroyed. I need to see my Web page without my App working on it obviously.

I'm using a FileProvider for this and this is what I've tried so far.
I obviously requested READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my Manifest and made it granted by the user.

My Manifest :

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:readPermission="true"
            android:writePermission="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

My provider_paths.xml :

```
<external-path path="Download/MyApp/" name="Download"/>
```

The code at the end of the pic generating process :

```
Uri uriForPic = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),imagefile);

intent.setDataAndType(uriForPic, "image/jpeg").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Not working. So I tried this one :

```
Uri uriForPic = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),imagefile);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Context context = MainActivity.this;

List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uriForPic, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

All is doing smooth until I try to open my html pages with my pics in them. Then, I got the `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial` error. This is weird since I can watch all my pics using the gallery without any exception.

I understand I must manually grant permission to each of my FileProvider generated Uris but these solutions don't work and after a week trying and googling, I'm lost and need your help...

So, two questions. Does my provider_paths.xml grant access to subfolders ? And what is missing in my understanding of permissions ?

Thanks for reading me,